# Imageview does not update if handler is used to post message

Tags: android, imageview

**Here is my code**

```
public void invalidateWidget(boolean invalidateUsingCaches) {
        mUpdatingWidget = true;

        if (invalidateUsingCaches) {
            widget.invalidateUsingCaches();
            if (widget.isRefreshRequired()) {
                widget.initializeRefreshRequired();
                mWidgetUpdateHandler.removeMessages(handlerMessage);
                mWidgetUpdateHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(handlerMessage,
                        handlerDelay);
            }
        } else {
            widget.invalidate(false);
        }

        refreshImageView();

        mUpdatingWidget = false;
    }
```

**This line**

```
mWidgetUpdateHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(handlerMessage,
                        handlerDelay);
```

causes imageview to not update with changes on phones with android versions 2.3 but works on newer android versions.

So far I have tried the following:

1. `imageview.invalidate();`
2. used a runnable with handler.
3. `activity.runOnUiThread();`

Remember the code works on newer android versions. Well it should work on all versions as the code follows Android guidelines.

Does anybody has a clue why this should be happenning? Solution?
Is MessageQueue has something to do here?

Comment: Did you check if the method returns true?  It's possible it's not being put in the queue.

Comment: I checked with Log.d, it is called, just the imageview does not update with new bitmap.

Comment: `Returns true if the message was successfully placed in to the message queue. Returns false on failure, usually because the looper processing the message queue is exiting.`  It's possible the message isn't being put in the queue at all for some reason.

Comment: Also, this may-or-may not be relevant.  Personally I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing. Unless your Handler is implementing something weird. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/LITKysqO0m0

Comment: It returns true. I saw the link you posted; it doesn't apply in my case as the delay is 1 second.   The logic here is to update with caches if user is doing some work and to update fully if idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with supplying new bitmap to imageview. In handler's handleMessage() I was giving new bitmap to the imageview which caused it to not refresh with changes. The handler worked fine. Though I still don't understand why imageview refused new bitmap on old android versions.

I solved the problem by keeping the same bitmap.